# Are there real normal matrices with non-negative entries that are asymmetric and non-circulant?

Tags: linear-algebra, spectral-graph-theory, circulant-matrices

Is there an example of a normal matrix with real non-negative entries that is neither symmetric nor circulant/block-circulant?

If not, is there a proof of this property/reference to proof?

Additionally, what if the entries on the diagonal are strictly 0, does this collapse the set of non-normal matrices onto symmetric or circulant/block-circulant matrices?

Thanks

Comment: Almost any square matrix will be non-normal and neither symmetric nor circulant.  Or do you want it to be **normal**, as in the title.

Comment: @RobertIsrael my apologies yes I want it to be normal - i will fix this

Answer (score 3):

For example, $$ \pmatrix{0 & 0 & 1 & 0\cr
                         0 & 0 & 0 & 1\cr
                         0 & 1 & 0 & 0\cr
                         1 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr} $$

Or, slightly more generally,
$$ \pmatrix{
b  & b +r  & a +s  & a  
\cr
 b +r  & b  & a  & a +s  
\cr
 a  & a +s  & c  & c +r  
\cr
 a +s  & a  & c +r  & c  
}$$